# Error number 5 when I try to run this VBA code

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub SOLAR()
'
' SOLAR Macro
' SOLAR CALCULATION
'

'
    Application.Goto Reference:="SOLAR"
    
    Dim c_size As Single
    Dim current As Integer
    Dim cable_length As Integer
    Dim voltage_drop_rate As Integer
    Dim c_capacity As Integer
    Dim v_drop As Integer
    Dim load As Integer
    Dim energy_units As Integer
    Dim panel_number As Single
    Dim energy As Integer
    Dim found As Integer
    Dim no_panels_req As Single
    Dim no_panels As Integer
    Dim panels As Integer
      
   'pick details from Panel size and calculate panel size
        
             If (load <> Empty) And (energy <> Empty) Then
                found = 0
                
   
                energy_units = Worksheets("SOLAR").Range("LOAD").Cells("I33").Value
                    load = Worksheets("SOLAR").Range("LOAD").Cells("I34").Value
                       PSH = Worksheets("SOLAR").Range("REGION").Cells("E24").Value
   
                                    no_panels_req = ((energy_units * 1.2) / PSH) * 1000
                   
                   no_panels = no_panels_req
                   
   End If
                panels = no_panels
                
End Sub
```

Comment: Application.Goto Reference:="SOLAR" is invalid. Reference needs to be a reference to a range (see excel vba help for details).

Comment: @Spinner - `Application.Goto Reference:="SOLAR"` works with a range named `SOLAR`. But perhaps OP meant `Worksheets("SOLAR").Activate`. Hard to know.

Comment: @BigBen: Yeah. I'm working on the assumption "SOLAR" is a sheet name [only] as it's used in that context within the code.

Comment: Error 5 will occur because of how you're using of .Cells (which is invalid). Cells requires row and column numbers (see excel  vba help for details).

Comment: Also, it seems odd to use of named range ("LOAD" for example) and then to seek an absolute address within that range. If a value sought is at "I33" (for example). It's simpler to write Worksheets("SOLAR").Range("I33"). Also note, you don't need .Value.

Comment: For whole numbers, you usually use only `As Long`, as for decimal numbers `As Double`. A variant variable is initialized with `Empty`, the numeric variables with `0` and the string variables with `""` (`vbNullString`), i.e. `load` and `energy` will never be `Empty`. Also, it's either `.Range("I33")` or `.Cells(33, "I")` or `.Cells(33, 9)`. You should share the named ranges' (`LOAD, REGION`) addresses and which cells should be used, so it can be fixed.

Comment: Well,the defined names are:LOAD,REGION and BOQSolar.The ranges used are I33,I34,E24,and E44.

Comment: I am trying to get a value from cell I33 in defined table name (LOAD),and a value from cell E24 in the defined table name (REGION) and performing the mathematical relation and feeding the result to cell E44 from defined table name(BoQSolar).

Comment: @Spinner,SOLAR is a sheet name.

Comment: Actually,this is what I;m getting.

Comment: Re 'SOLAR is a sheet name.': Then my opening comment above is relevant (i.e. `Application.Goto Reference:="SOLAR"` won't work). To activate that sheet, you'd use `Worksheets("SOLAR").Activate`.

Answer (score -2):

Per my comment above, a cause of your reported error 5 is invalid syntax of the Cells property. As suggested, take a look at help, and you'll learn: 
o  Syntax for Cells is `Cells(row, column)`, not `Cells(address)` as you have in your code.
o  `row` and `column` can be a numeric, an equation that results in a numeric, or variable containing a numeric.

In addition (not covered in help):
o  `column` may be a string column reference, e.g.: `Cells(1, "A")`
o  excel automatically converts the column reference to a column number
o  Thus `Cells(1, "A")` is the same as `Cells(1, 1)`

It's the `Cells(address)` syntax that's throwing the error 5
Correct that and you'll solve your error 5 issue.

A second order issue (that I also commented on) is the way you're using absolute addresses within named ranges. However, I think, once you have a better understanding of how the Cells property works, you'll sort soon that out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239169/discussion-between-spinner-and-chris-neilsen).